# Python logging won't set a logging level using basicConfig

Tags: python, logging, error-logging

For some reason,  `logging.basicConfig` is ignoring the logger level that I'm giving it. The following code is in a script of mine:

```
# main.py
print logging.getLogger().getEffectiveLevel()
print logger_level
logging.basicConfig(format=logger_format,
                    level=logger_level,
                    )
print logging.getLogger().getEffectiveLevel()
```

The output is:

```
30
10
30
```

So, it's not actually setting the logger level. However, if I execute this exact code in an interactive interpreter, I get the following output:

```
30
10
10
```

Which means I'm setting the logging level just fine. Even more confusing, this is a recent occurrence – I don't know what I did that caused this behaviour. Can anyone provide some insight?

Edit: In case of related questions, I've tried running `main.py` both from my IDE (Sublime Text) as well as from the command line, both with the same result. I'm working in a conda-based virtual environment, and I've tried running the code both in the environment and not (but only from the interpreter - the script can't handle the general environment) with the same result.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [python logging module docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig),

> This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured for it.

My assumption is that you called `basicConfig()` prior, which installs handlers.

Try setting the loglevel directly on the root logger.

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logger_level)
```

If you want to change the formatting, then you'll need to give the handler a new formatter. The following *might* work, assuming a handler has already been added to the root logger.

```
logging.getLogger().handlers[0].setFormatter(logging.Formatter(logger_format))
```

Comment: `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logger_level)` definitely worked. I must be inadvertently calling `logging.info` or something similar in some other file before `main.py` loads. Thanks!

Comment: I read that there's a `force` parameter on `basicConfig`. However it doesn't seem to work. The docs seem to indicate that it would force the configuration on the root logger. Oh I just realized that `force` is only in Python 3.8 and not in Python 3.7.

Comment: In my case, I was using the `tornado.log` module in addition to python's `logging`. It was overwriting the `level` setting, so I rearranged my code and it works now.

Answer (score 10):

An issue I (stupidly) had was not putting `logging.basicConfig()` at the top of the main file.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig):

> The above module-level convenience functions *(debug, info, warn, error, fatal)*, which delegate to the root logger, call basicConfig() to ensure that at least one handler is available.

> This function *(`basicConfig()`)* does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured, unless the keyword argument `force` is set to True.

I called a function which logged a message before calling `logging.BasicConfig()` in my script, so the logger's level was set to the default, rather than the level I wanted.

If it's not possible to move the logger higher in the file, you have two options:

**Python 3.8 and above:**

```py
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, force=True)
```

**Python 2.x and Python 3.x:**

```py
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logger_level)
```

---

To see `basicConfig()` overwriting in action, try this:

```py
import logging

logging.info("Can't see me!")
logging.warn("Peekabo")

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.info("Hidden again!")

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, force=True)
logging.info("You found me!")
```